# Hide class before document

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have about 20 tabs which are placed underneath the content (not on-top as usual) with large content (forms,inputs) on each tabs.

Problem is that when the users visit the site, they see all the content before the tabs hide. Is there a way to prevent this? I am using jQuery tabs as simple as:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $(".tab_content").hide();$(".tab_content:first").show();
});
```

I was thinking if there is a way to hide **.tab_content** without jQuery? So I can load jquery at the end asynchronously. I would imagine, loading jquery and then hiding tabs takes time. But yet again I was thinking that, in order to hide .tab_content you need the content so, maybe there is no way around it? 
Thanks alot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `hide` comes into play after the DOM is ready or the element you are applying `hide` is inside the `DOM` so a better way is to add a class that hides the element

```
.tab_content
{
   display: none
}
```

and

```
$(function(){
$(".tab_content:first").show();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you simply want to hide then you can use pure CSS:

```
.tab_content{
   display:none;
   /* or */
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

Once your page has loaded and jQuery is ready you can then show it as required.

Answer (score 2):

Use CSS to hide the tabs by default:

```
.tab_content { display: none; }
```

Show them when ready.

Answer (score 2):

You can prevent showing them by default using css.

```
.tab_content { display: none; }
```

Answer (score 2):

the best way is to do it in css, that way it will never show up when the page loads

`.tab_content { display: none }`